Amcharts5 XY-Charts Change color of columns (fill color and stroke color)
I have this AmCharts5 XY-chart:

I want to change it so that each column gets its own color:

I have added fillColor1 and strokeColor1 to each dictionary in the data list. I need to use them when I generate the bars.
HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Graph</h1>

<div id="chartdiv_total_count_risk" style="width: 100%;height: 80vh;"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>


<script src="graph.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

graph.js
// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv_total_count_risk");


// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);


// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
  panX: false,
  panY: false,
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));





// Set data
var data = [
  {
      xlabel: "None",
      value1: 5,
      fillColor1: "#cccccc",
      strokeColor1: "#7a7a7a"
  },
  {
      xlabel: "Low",
      value1: 11,
      fillColor1: "#0acb8e",
      strokeColor1: "#0c664a"
  },
  {
      xlabel: "Medium",
      value1: 3,
      fillColor1: "#fec400",
      strokeColor1: "#806300"
  },
  {
      xlabel: "High",
      value1: 5,
      fillColor1: "#fe5461",
      strokeColor1: "#7a030c"
  },
  {
      xlabel: "Critical",
      value1: 5,
      fillColor1: "#000000",
      strokeColor1: "#000000"
  }
]

// Create axes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
  categoryField: "xlabel",
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
    minGridDistance: 40,
    minorGridEnabled: false
  }),
  tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
}));

xAxis.data.setAll(data);

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
}));


// Add series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
function makeSeries(name, fieldName) {
  var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
    name: name,
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueYField: fieldName,
    categoryXField: "xlabel"
  }));

  series.columns.template.setAll({
    tooltipText: "{categoryX} {name}: {valueY}",
    width: am5.percent(90),
    tooltipY: 0
  });

  series.data.setAll(data);

}


makeSeries("Criticality", "value1");


// Make stuff animate on load
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/#Forcing_appearance_animation
chart.appear(1000, 100);

